# component not install in nuxt.js

Tags: git, npm, vue.js, nuxt.js

I create new file testcomp.vue

in pages/index.vue I add

```
import testcomp from 'components/testcomp'
```

in **export default{}** i add

```
components:{
    'testcomp': testcomp,
},
```

after this I run **npm install --save components/testcomp**

in console log I see next

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/components/testcomp.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-02T17_38_50_009Z-debug.log
```

Why it?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the error because you are treating your newly created component as if it were an npm package.

npm install --save package/name is only needed when you are wanting to install a new remote package. Not for content created on your computer.

On another note, if you're using the default next setup. I think your import does not match the file structure. I think you need import testcomp from '../components/testcomp'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
import testcomp from '~/components/testcomp'

export default {
    components: {
        testcomp
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.